# Kepp getting a ValueError error type while running model.fit()

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

Running the model.fit() method on my training and validation dataset, I keep getting this error, and I am not sure what it is about:

```
ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
  Positional arguments (4 total):
    * Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(224, 224, 3), dtype=float32)
    * False
    * False
    * 0.99
  Keyword arguments: {}

Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):
```

```
  hist = model.fit(x=EXAMPLES_TRAIN,
                   steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
                   validation_data=EXAMPLES_VALID,
                   validation_steps=validation_steps,
                   epochs=_NUM_EPOCHS,
                   callbacks=
                     tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(s_dir),      # log metrics
                     hp.KerasCallback(s_dir, s_hparams),         # log hparams
                     EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', baseline=_CHKPT_ES_BASELINE, patience=_CHKPT_ES_PATIENCE, verbose=1),  # early stopping],
                   verbose=1).history
```

I don't mind sharing more details to give more insight on my problem. Any idea on what I might be doing wrong, because I have similar code, where it works well, without this error.

Comment: UPDATE: This error does not persist when I don't include a `validation_data` in `model.fit(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try a dummy call to your model before loading the weights:

```
model = build_model(...) # Your model-building code
model(tf.zeros((224, 224, 3), tf.float32)

# load model weights
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was not trying to load weights. Not sure why that is the error being spewed. I built the model from the headless module from Hub. But as soon, as I pass in my training and validation examples, I get the error.

Comment: UPDATE: I only get the error when I have a validation set. What can that be about?